# Audio widget within Jupyter notebook is **not** playing. How can I get the widget to play the audio?

Tags: visual-studio-code, audio, jupyter-notebook, widget, ipython

I writing my code within a Jupyter notebook in VS Code. I am hoping to play some of the audio within my data set. However, when I execute the cell, the console reports no errors, produces the widget, but the widget displays 0:00 / 0:00 (see below), indicating there is no sound to play.

[image: screen cap of audio widget within .ipynb]

Below, I have listed two ways to reproduce the error.

1. I have acquired data from the [hub data store](https://github.com/activeloopai/Hub). Looking specifically at the [spoken MNIST](https://docs.activeloop.ai/datasets/spoken-mnist-dataset) data set, I cannot get the data from the `audio` tensor to play

```py
import hub
from IPython.display import display, Audio
from ipywidgets import interactive

# Obtain the data using the hub module
ds = hub.load("hub://activeloop/spoken_mnist")

# Create widget
sample = ds.audio[0].numpy()
display(Audio(data=sample, rate = 8000, autoplay=True))
```

2. The second example is a test (copied from another [post](https://notebook.community/pioneers/topgear/ipython-in-depth/examples/Interactive%20Widgets/Beat%20Frequencies)) that I ran to see if it was something wrong with the data or something wrong with my console, environment, *etc.*

```py
# Same imports as shown above

# Toy Function to play beats in notebook
def beat_freq(f1=220.0, f2=224.0):
    max_time = 5
    rate = 8000
    times = np.linspace(0,max_time,rate*max_time)
    signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*times) + np.sin(2*np.pi*f2*times)
    display(Audio(data=signal, rate=rate))
    return signal

v = interactive(beat_freq, f1=(200.0,300.0), f2=(200.0,300.0))
display(v)
```

I believe that if it is something wrong with the data (this is a well-known data set so, I doubt it), then only the second one will play. If it is something to do with the IDE or something else, then neither will work, as is the case now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the late reply! In the future, please tag the questions with activeloop so it's easier to sort through (or hit us up directly in community slack -> [slack.activeloop.ai](https://slack.activeloop.ai)).

Regarding the [Free Spoken Digit Dataset](https://docs.activeloop.ai/datasets/free-spoken-digit-dataset-fsdd), I managed to track the error with your usage of [activeloop hub](https://docs.activeloop.ai/) and audio display.

adding [:,0] to 9th line will help fixing display on Colab as Audio expects one-dimensional data

```
%matplotlib inline
import hub
from IPython.display import display, Audio
from ipywidgets import interactive

# Obtain the data using the hub module
ds = hub.load("hub://activeloop/spoken_mnist")

# Create widget
sample = ds.audio[0].numpy()[:,0]
display(Audio(data=sample, rate = 8000, autoplay=True))
```

(When we uploaded the dataset, we decided to upload the audio as (N,C) where C is the number of channels, which happens to be 1 for the particular dataset. The added dimension wasn't added automatically)

Regarding the VScode... the audio, unfortunately, would still not work (not because of us, but VScode), but you can still try visualizing [Free Spoken Digit Dataset](https://app.activeloop.ai/activeloop/spoken_mnist) (you can play the music there, too). Hopefully this addresses your needs!

Let us know if you have further questions.

Mikayel from Activeloop

Comment: Thanks, @mikayelh. Unfortunately, that did not work for me. 

I tried your solution on VSCode (Mac M1), and I tried it on Google Colab. On both platforms, I received an initial error: 

`ModuleNotFoundError: Miniaudio is not installed. Run 'pip install hub[audio]'.`

I proceeded to install it as instructed but received the error above again. 

I have `hub==2.3.1` (VSCode) and `hub==2.3.1` (Colab)

What am I missing to get your solution to work?

Comment: Hey @MoyoAjayi. So Miniaudio is not compatible with M1 as far as I know, so I am afraid that's an external dependency we can't fix. 

As for the Colab, that's odd. I tested on my end and it works. Can you [try this one please](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IsgPesKXWSy81AWoRWIuAxuZLQzekkxO?usp=sharing), or share example Colab that doesn't work for you? Thanks!

Comment: The link you sent worked. 

I understand M1 is not supported yet, but I hope it will be soon. 

So, if you click on this version of the [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14vUyakPUXWECk61xeNmTGK6x00dh3yda?usp=sharing) you will see an error after the third cell.

However, when I ran the [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bjmCq3EJ8bW6fNOPKs8Y4end9LmhhYKo?usp=sharing) again today, for some reason, I did **not** get an error. 

Either way, I will use Colab on my M1 when using Activeloop until M1 is supported.

Comment: @MoyoAjayi nice! you'd need to share access for me to look at it. If you have any questions, feel free to post them here or our community slack, [slack.activeloop.ai](slack.activeloop.ai).

Comment: Hi @mikayelh, thank you for providing me with help earlier. For your edification, I have updated the permission to the notebook with an error [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14vUyakPUXWECk61xeNmTGK6x00dh3yda?usp=sharing), and I have updated permissions to the notebook without the error [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bjmCq3EJ8bW6fNOPKs8Y4end9LmhhYKo?usp=sharing).